# Moderator Tools: Flag Or Disagree - How do I "disagree"?

Tags: support

While perusing the available moderator actions available via Moderator Tools, I found a flag with which I disagree. (An answer was flagged as "low quality", but IMHO adequately resolves the issue (and was indicated by the OP as the correct answer).

However, when clicking the "Flag or Disagree" button in the hope of disagreeing (rather than flagging), I found no option to "disagree."

Is the option unavailable, or is this a case of PEBKAC?

[image]

Comment: Screenshot might be helpful because this is kind of stuff users see differently depending on rep and such.

Comment: In any case the moderators will look in to it and probably come to the same conclusion you did and decline that flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added a screen shot to your post that I made on Stack Overflow where I am in a very similar situation: I have access to the 10k moderator tools.

Choose the **invalid flag** option to disagree.

There is an explaining [answer from Grace](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95607/why-do-disagree-with-flag-votes-have-to-go-through-a-moderator/95624#95624) about that thing on meta.so:

> Furthermore, these "disagree" flags are distinguished sharply from other flags, which means it's easy to spot when a flagged post is unanimous versus contested. As such, if you disagree with a flag, then flagging that "invalid" there is the best way to express it. It does nothing towards supporting the existing flags, it only opposes them.

See also:

- [10k+ users can see flags now, but can't unflag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94186/10k-users-can-see-flags-now-but-cant-unflag)
- [How and when should we use the “invalid flag” flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94133/how-and-when-should-we-use-the-invalid-flag-flag)

The effect of these “counter-flags” is that we moderators can see the initial flag and the disagree together. This is especially useful when a flag is ambiguous or when it needs some research to decide about it.

Comment: Hmm... I don't remember seeing an "Invalid Flag" option, and (un)fortunately, there's nothing in the flag queue right now. I'll keep checking and report back.

Comment: Finally encountered a flag for review, and verified that the **"Invalid Flag"** option **is** available.